# Moq: Verifying protected method on abstract class is called

Tags: c#-4.0, methods, tdd, moq, verify

This is my test

```
[TestClass]
public class RepositoryTests
{
    private APurchaseOrderRepository _repository;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _repository = new FakePurchaseOrderRepository();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RepositoryGetPurchaseOrdersForStoreCallsValidatePurchaseOrders()
    {
        var store = new Store();
        var mockRepo = new Mock<APurchaseOrderRepository>();
        mockRepo.Protected().Setup("ValidatePurchaseOrders", ItExpr.IsAny<List<PurchaseOrder>>());

        _repository.GetPurchaseOrders(store);

        mockRepo.Protected().Verify("ValidatePurchaseOrders", Times.Once(), ItExpr.IsAny<List<PurchaseOrder>>());
    } 
}
```

APurchaseOrderRepository and it's interface look like this

```
public interface IPurchaseOrderRepository
{
    List<PurchaseOrder> GetPurchaseOrders(Store store);
}

public abstract class APurchaseOrderRepository : IPurchaseOrderRepository
{
    public abstract List<PurchaseOrder> GetPurchaseOrders(Store store);

    protected virtual bool ValidatePurchaseOrders(List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my Fake

```
public class FakePurchaseOrderRepository : APurchaseOrderRepository
{
    public override List<PurchaseOrder> GetPurchaseOrders(Store store)
    {
        var purchaseOrders = new List<PurchaseOrder>();

        ValidatePurchaseOrders(purchaseOrders);

        return purchaseOrders;
    }
}
```

However, my test fails with:

> Test method
>   PreSwapTests.RepositoryTests.RepositoryGetPurchaseOrdersForStoreCallsValidatePurchaseOrders
>   threw exception:  Moq.MockException:  Expected invocation on the mock
>   once, but was 0 times: mock =>
>   mock.ValidatePurchaseOrders(It.IsAny())
>
> Configured setups: mock =>
>   mock.ValidatePurchaseOrders(It.IsAny()), Times.Never No
>   invocations performed.

What am I doing wrong?

Notes:

- Moq.4.0.10827

Update:

I think it is this line `mockRepo.Protected().Setup("ValidatePurchaseOrders");`, because I need to add the parameters to it as a second argument, but I can't seem to get it correct.

Update 2:
Made some modifications, now it compiles, but isn't counting correctly...or something, error message and code are both updated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized I was doing this all wrong, changed my objects to work with this test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RepositoryGetPurchaseOrdersForStoreCallsValidatePurchaseOrders()
    {
        var store = new Store();

        var mockPurchaseOrderProvider = new Mock<IPurchaseOrderProvider>();
        var mockPurchaseOrderValidator = new Mock<IPurchaseOrderValidator>();
        var purchaseOrderRepository = new PurchaseOrderRepository(mockPurchaseOrderProvider.Object, mockPurchaseOrderValidator.Object);

        mockPurchaseOrderValidator.Setup(x => x.ValidatePurchaseOrders(It.IsAny<List<PurchaseOrder>>()));

        purchaseOrderRepository.GetPurchaseOrders(store);

        mockPurchaseOrderValidator.Verify(x => x.ValidatePurchaseOrders(It.IsAny<List<PurchaseOrder>>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

This is a much better structure now I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ValidatePurchaseOrders` is not in your `IPurchaseOrderRepository` interface.

The repository is declared as `private IPurchaseOrderRepository _repository;` so it can only see what is in the interface.

Comment: Changed to `private APurchaseOrderRepository _repository;`, same error

Comment: Ah, it's because it is a protected member. Either make it public, or this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883835/verify-that-a-base-protected-method-is-called-with-moq-3-1

Comment: I think it is this line mockRepo.Protected().Setup("ValidatePurchaseOrders");, because I need to add the parameters to it as a second argument, but I can't seem to get it correct.

Comment: It is possible, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728873/verify-the-number-of-times-a-protected-method-is-called-using-moq